# Same EndPoint with different pathvariables

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data

I'm facing a little issue during my current project, by making multiple endpoints with the same URI but with different pathvariables as shown in the code below:

```
@GetMapping(value= { "/users",
                     "/users/{grade}/{profession}",
                     "/users/{region}/{profession}",
                     "/users/{region}/{grade}",  
})
public List<AppUser> filtreListUsers(
            @PathVariable Optional<String> region,
            @PathVariable Optional<String> profession,
            @PathVariable Optional<String> grade
        
){ 
        if(profession.isPresent() && grade.isPresent()) {
             return accountService.filtreListUsers(profession.get(), grade.get());
        }
        if(region.isPresent()  && profession.isPresent() ) {
             return accountService.filtreUsersByRegionProfession(region.get(), profession.get());
        }
        if(region.isPresent()  && grade.isPresent()) {
             return accountService.filtreUsersByRegionGrade(region.get(), grade.get());
        }   
        return accountService.listUsers();
}
```

The result that i attend should be like :
**http://localhost:8084/users/region/grade** : should gives me the list of users by both variabes

**http://localhost:8084/users/region/profession** : should gives me the list of users by both variabes

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoints are conflicting. I suggest you use query params for filtering not path variables.

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<AppUser> filtreListUsers(
            @RequestParam Optional<String> region,
            @RequestParam Optional<String> profession,
            @RequestParam Optional<String> grade
        
){ 
        if(profession.isPresent() && grade.isPresent()) {
             return accountService.filtreListUsers(profession.get(), grade.get());
        }
        if(region.isPresent()  && profession.isPresent() ) {
             return accountService.filtreUsersByRegionProfession(region.get(), profession.get());
        }
        if(region.isPresent()  && grade.isPresent()) {
             return accountService.filtreUsersByRegionGrade(region.get(), grade.get());
        }   
        return accountService.listUsers();
}
```

Some of your possible URLs

```
/users?grade=xyz&region=abc&profession=123
/users?grade=xyz&region=abc
/users?grade=xyz&profession=123
/users?region=abc&profession=123
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, its working fine with params. @ZohaibAhmed

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it worked out for you. Thanks